# SSRS not showing all rows by level (hierarchy)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Ok folks, this is driving me crazy...

I have a report that pulls back details for a number of features. THese features can hang off others, exist in their own right or both.

I have the following data as the result of the query:

```
Feature_ID   Parent_ID
24            
24          25
20            
26          12
12            
21          23
26          20
22            
24          23
23          26
24          27
27          28
24          22
29          20
23            
25            
27          29
22          26
28          12
```

As you can see, some of the features fit in multiple places in the hierarchy. However, all I get back in the report is:

[image: SSRS output]

I am grouping on Feature_ID, recursive parent is Parent_ID. What am I missing?

Comment: What should be your result? I see your tablix is showing wrong data since 24 should be in `level 0`, so what is the level expression you are using?

Comment: @alejandrozuleta I am using `=level()` for the level field.

Comment: What is you expected result?

Comment: Calm down, folks. I've cracked it! I pulled the full hierarchy path for each Feature_ID and the corresponding path for each parent as part of the query.

Answer (score 5):

By your wording and unexpected output it feels like you are looking for a list of distinct levels and features. Hopefully the following is helpful. If not, perhaps you can provide some additional context to understand what you are looking for.

```
declare @table table (Feature_ID int, Parent_ID int);

insert @table values
(24,null),
(24,25),
(20,null),
(26,12),
(12,null),
(21,23),
(26,20),
(22,null),
(24,23),
(23,26),
(24,27),
(27,28),
(24,22),
(29,20),
(23,null),
(25,null),
(27,29),
(22,26),
(28,12);

select * from @table order by 1,2;
select * from @table order by 2,1;

with cte as (
        select  Feature_ID, Parent_ID, 0 [Level], CAST(Feature_ID as varchar(200)) [Path]
        from    @table
        where   Parent_ID is null

        union   all

        select  t.Feature_ID, t.Parent_ID, c.[Level] + 1, cast(c.[Path] + '|' + CAST(t.Feature_ID as varchar(200)) as varchar(200))
        from    @table t
        join    cte c
                on c.Feature_ID = t.Parent_ID
)
select  distinct [Level], Feature_ID
from    cte
order   by [Level], Feature_ID;
```

This gives the following result:

```
Level   Feature_ID
0   12
0   20
0   22
0   23
0   24
0   25
1   21
1   24
1   26
1   28
1   29
2   22
2   23
2   27
3   21
3   24
```